# How to use filter across and str_detect together to filter conditional on mutlitple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr, across

**I have this dataframe:**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("Z2", "A2", "B2", "C2", "A2", "E2", "F2", 
"G2"), col2 = c("Z2", "Z2", "A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "A2", "F2"
), col3 = c("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "Z2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

> df
  col1 col2 col3
1   Z2   Z2   A2
2   A2   Z2   B2
3   B2   A2   C2
4   C2   B2   D2
5   A2   C2   E2
6   E2   D2   F2
7   F2   A2   G2
8   G2   F2   Z2
```

I would like to use explicitly `filter`, `across` and `str_detect` in a `tidyverse` setting to filter all rows that start with an `A` over `col1:col3`.

**Expected result:**

```
  col1 col2 col3
1   Z2   Z2   A2
2   A2   Z2   B2
3   B2   A2   C2
4   A2   C2   E2
5   F2   A2   G2
```

**I have tried:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    filter(across(c(col1, col2, col3), ~str_detect(., "^A")))
```

**This gives:**

```
[1] col1 col2 col3
<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)
```

I want to learn why this code is not working using `filter`, `across` and `str_detect`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `if_any` as `across` will look for `&` condition i.e. all columns should meet the condition for a particular row to get `filter`ed

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    filter(if_any(everything(), ~str_detect(., "^A")))
```

-output

```
   col1 col2 col3
1   Z2   Z2   A2
2   A2   Z2   B2
3   B2   A2   C2
4   A2   C2   E2
5   F2   A2   G2
```

---

According to `?across`

> if_any() and if_all() apply the same predicate function to a selection of columns and combine the results into a single logical vector: if_any() is TRUE when the predicate is TRUE for any of the selected columns, if_all() is TRUE when the predicate is TRUE for all selected columns.

> across() supersedes the family of "scoped variants" like summarise_at(), summarise_if(), and summarise_all().

The `if_any/if_all` are not part of the scoped variants

Comment: Thank you akrun. As scoped verbs (_if, _at, _all) have been superseded by the use of `across()` in an existing verb, I thought to use `filter, across and str_detect` like in other use cases?! Why it is not possible?

Comment: @TarJae `if_any` or `if_all` are differet and is not part of `filter_all` or `filter_at` etc.  I think this was introduced because of limitations in `across`